# Firefox download for different OSes?

Tags: firefox, download

I'm having trouble finding Firefox's download page. I'm working on my MacBook and trying to download Firefox for Windows because the server's security policy is aggressive, and IE cannot perform the download. The Mozilla server tries to serve the download, but the Windows server blocks it.

When I visit the Firefox download page returned from a Google search, the result is a web page with the message *"Your system doesn't meet the requirements to run Firefox"*:

[image]

How do I find the Firefox downloads for other OSes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the question again *ahem* (sorry)... You can find the link to download whichever OS install you need [HERE](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/)

Comment: Thank you very much. How did you find it? The top Google hits and the paid advertisement took me to the broken download page. Related, do you know if Firefox offers an FTP or SFTP site? I think I need it for the Android version of Firefox. I don't us Google Play, so I don't have access to the APK through trusted channels.

Comment: I don't remember the exact way I got there before, but on my phone the link is at the bottom of the main page. It's called "Firefox for other platforms & languages".

Comment: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/android/all/